# Multiple lines forced with jquery.customSelect plugin for dropdown forms

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is a weird problem I'm having with a jQuery plugin for dropdown forms (plugin homepage: http://adam.co/lab/jquery/customselect/)

For some reason after a number of characters, the option title forces itself to 2 or more lines. I have tried changing the width of the box, but this solves nothing.

Here's an example of what I mean:

http://jsfiddle.net/hysHB/999/

```
<select class="styled">
  <option value="">This should all be on one line</option>
  <option value="one">two</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add to your css

```
.customSelectInner{
    width:100% !important;
}
```

You can change style for this classe too

```
.customSelect { 
/* This is the default class that is used */
/* Put whatever custom styles you want here */
}

.customSelect.customSelectHover {
/* Styles for when the select box is hovered */
}

.customSelect.customSelectOpen {
/* Styles for when the select box is open */
}

.customSelect.customSelectFocus {
/* Styles for when the select box is in focus */
}

.customSelectInner {
/* You can style the inner box too */
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried .customSelectInner but didn't think to use !important. Seems to be working fine now.

Comment: @AndSmith in the plugin there is .css() , which sets width.